# Click behaviour - Difference in IE and FF?

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, firefox, click, behavior

i just came to the conclusion that a project i am currently working on might have a "logical" error in functionality.

Currently I'am using server technology with PHP/MySQL and JQuery.
Within the page there's a normal link reference with tag

```
<a href="contentpage?page=xxx">next step</a>
```

The pain point now seems to be the given jquery click event on the same element. The intension was to save the (current) content of the page (-> form elements) via another php script using the php session command.
For any reason, IE can handle the click event of Jquery right before executing the standard html command, that reloads the current page again with the new page parameter. By using FF the behaviour is different. I assume, that FF first execute the html command and afterwards execute the javascript code which handles the click event. Therefore the resultset here is wrong respectivly empty.

My question now is whether you made the same experience and how you handled / wordarrounded this problem.

I'd be thankful fur any of your tips or further feedback. Maybe you also have a solution on how to rethink about the current architecture.

Regards,
Oliver

Comment: The question is unclear. I think there is no "standard html command".

Comment: @Dor he means, "the native action resulting from a click on an `<a>` element", I think.

Answer (score 1):

actually firefox do raise the event and execute the command that is attached to it before the hyperlink takes the redirecting action, maybe an error happened while executing the command and IE allowed it to complete  its action while firefox throw an error and jQuery function block handled it which you will not notice an exception was thrown.
make a test button with classical onclick event and test your function and see if it is working probably in firefox

Comment: Dear Kronass,
I first had also this opinion and therefore had a try with several methods with the ajax-function and examples out of some tutorials. When I deleted the respective href parameter, it worked perfectly. So I assumed that the combination of my code structure was not very senseful. this is why I wanted to start a discussion on this on how to manage this on a much better way...
Thanks for you reply anyway :)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you are assigning a `click` event to the link, leaving the `href` in place and ready to fire. That is very unwise, as the time left for any javascript in the `click` event to execute when the user clicks the link is limited, and arbitrary. It can well be that different browsers handle this differently - anyway, it's the wrong approach. You can never be sure your actions get executed in full.

The usual approach would be to have the `click` event `return false`, preventing the default action of the link to fire, and do a relaxed `location.href = this.href` when everything is done.

If you are using Ajax to send away some data, then put the `location.href` part into the `success` callback of your Ajax call. That way, you can be 100% sure the data gets sent.

Comment: Hey Pekky,
thanks for your comment. Of course I gave some thoughts in this type of structure. The more I balance the overall possibilities I came to the same point of view. I wanted to have just clearfied the situation as I already assumed that my probityry approach is not very wiseful. I think I'll give it this way. 

Of course the current procedure is very quick 'n dirty, so this was the cause to startover this discussion :)

Thanks for your efforts and participation on this :)